# Gradle could not start your build

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am getting an error with Gradle every time I try to run a program in android studio. I believe this error was caused by me closing out of android studio while Gradle was loading something and it didn't complete its task. I have seen some people online suggest `.\gradlew --stop` which doesn't seem to be working. Has anyone encountered the same issue?

```
> Cannot create service of type BuildTreeActionExecutor using method LauncherServices$ToolingBuildTreeScopeServices.createActionExecutor() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<BuildActionRunner>.
   > Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal().
      > Timeout waiting to lock journal cache (C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\journal-1). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
        Owner PID: 5916
        Our PID: 30496
        Owner Operation: 
        Our operation: 
        Lock file: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\journal-1\journal-1.lock

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.initialization.exception.InitializationException: Gradle could not start your build.
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.collectFailures(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:65)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:48)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Cannot create service of type BuildTreeActionExecutor using method LauncherServices$ToolingBuildTreeScopeServices.createActionExecutor() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<BuildActionRunner>.
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:798)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.prepare(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:683)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:706)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$OwnServices.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:442)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$CompositeServiceProvider.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:991)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1077)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:321)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:103)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type FileAccessTimeJournal using GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal().
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:896)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:834)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:820)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:834)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:820)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:834)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:820)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:834)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.createServiceInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:820)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:606)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getCollectionService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1124)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.getCollectionService(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1106)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.find(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:1069)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1600(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.bind(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:796)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.LockTimeoutException: Timeout waiting to lock journal cache (C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\journal-1). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: 5916
Our PID: 30496
Owner Operation: 
Our operation: 
Lock file: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\journal-1\journal-1.lock
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.timeoutException(DefaultFileLockManager.java:344)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:305)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:164)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:110)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.incrementLockCount(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.acquireFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:168)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.onStartWork(DefaultCacheAccess.java:375)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:211)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:201)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:292)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:61)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.createCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.createCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:194)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileAccessTimeJournal.<init>(DefaultFileAccessTimeJournal.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GradleUserHomeScopeServices.createFileAccessTimeJournal(GradleUserHomeScopeServices.java:241)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:894)
    ... 95 more
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcvqZ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Iyhl.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Exit Android Studio
2. Kill all Gradle processes
3. Delete `C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\journal-1\journal-1.lock`
4. Try again

Answer (score 2):

I was trying in visual studio code terminal(powershell/cmd) use -> `./gradlew --stop`

but if you don't want to use this then simply restart your PC

Answer (score 0):

Simply execute the below command in your terminal/command prompt and the error should be resolved

taskkill /F /PID

Answer (score 0):

If using 2 different version of Android Studio. Close both and just restart the pc and then just open the Android Studio you were facing the problem. Doing so will end the gradle process and there won't be any issue. Running different Android Studio Version at a same time will cause such problems.